# search a particular key in mongodb collection using php

Tags: php, mongodb, search

I have this mongodb collection.

```
{
"_id" : "3",
"SETTINGS" : {
    "PRIVACY" : {
        "ALLOW_SUGGESTIONS" : NumberLong(1),
        "BIRTHDAY" : NumberLong(0),
        "CONTACT_INFO" : {
            "PHONE" : NumberLong(0),
            "ADDRESS" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "SEARCH_ENGINE" : NumberLong(0)
    }
}
```

I tried searching for a `PHONE` using php. Problem is that all the codes I have tried takes takes out a document and then I have to take out the key `PHONE` from document on my own.

My attempt was:-

```
$cursor=$collection->find(array('_id'=>'3'),array('SETTINGS'=>array('PRIVACY'=>array('CONTACT_INFO'=>array('PHONE')))));
```

`foreach ($cursor as $document)
    {
    echo var_dump($document);
    }`

It gives me output:-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'localhost:27017: Can't canonicalize query: BadValue Unsupported projection option: SETTINGS: { PRIVACY: { CONTACT_INFO: [ "PHONE" ] } }' in /var/www/html/ProjectTest/include/Profile Helper.php:114 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/ProjectTest/include/Profile Helper.php(114): MongoCursor->rewind() #1 /var/www/html/ProjectTest/profile.php(14): Profile->GetProfileInfo() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/ProjectTest/include/Profile Helper.php on line 114
```

### Summarizing my questions:-

- Is there a way to takes search on this particular key and not the whole document.
- If yes then which way will be better considering performance or searching speed in huge database.

Comment: Would be better if you edited your question to show your attempt as well.

Comment: @chridam I only found ways to extract particular document and not to extract a `key` nested deep into document. So, my attempts to do that are pretty lame sir. Can you suggest a way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would have been easier if you provided a code example of what output you'd like, and code of what you tried. You can try:

```
$db->$collection->find(array('SETTINGS.PRIVACY.CONTACT_INFO.PHONE' => 0))
```

This code will get you the document with phone equal `0`

To return only the phone, you have to use [projection](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.find.php):

```
$db->$collection->find(array('SETTINGS.PRIVACY.CONTACT_INFO.PHONE' => 0), array('_id' => 0, 'SETTINGS.PRIVACY.CONTACT_INFO.PHONE' => 1))
```

**EDIT:** According to the edition of your question, you lack the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#read-operations-embedded-documents)

Comment: That's the thing I was looking for. Now it works for me.